# Laravel - Middleware How to change route to our desired page other than Login

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3, middleware

I m working on fresh laravel project.

I had install the laravel framework through composer then I created a route for testing purpose like this:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
return view('pages.home');
 });
```

This worked fine and I got the desired page. Now for understanding middleware I added this line of code:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
return view('pages.home');
 })->middleware('auth');
```

Now its throwing error of

```
Route [login] not defined.
```

What I know that, it throwing this error because I havent install any voyagers package thats why it not finding `'login'` route.

But My question is How can I change that `Route [login]` to my desired page like `Route [pages.notauth]`.

Please help me for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First run `php artisan make:auth` to make the Laravel auth boilerplate. Then in the `LoginController` add the the following:

```
class LoginController extends Controller {
    use AuthenticatesUsers;
    protected $redirectTo = '/home';

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
    }
 
    public function showLoginForm() {
           return view("pages.notlogin");
     }


 }
```

#### Update

The `php artisan make:auth` command is no longer available in the base Laravel installation. Since Laravel 6 to get a roughly equivalent effect you need to (a) install [laravel/ui](https://github.com/laravel/ui) and (b) run:

```
php artisan ui bootstrap --auth
```

You can also use react or vue instead of bootstrap depending what you want to use in your UI.

Comment: How can I use without running php artisan make:auth

Comment: You need to register your own `Route::get("login",callback or controller action)->name("login");` but that means that you're not getting a lot of the already built-in default things

Answer (score 1):

You're getting the message `Route [login] not defined.` not because you've not installed Voyager package, but because you've not created or defined any Routes for general authentication.

Yes, if you install Voyager package, then the error message will be gone because package itself will create the necessary auth routes and controllers.

In order to do that you've to run `php artisan make:auth` in command line.

In laravel 5.4, all the middlewares have been registered in the

```
app\Http\Kernel.php
```

In the file, you'll see that

protected $routeMiddleware = [
    'auth' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate::class,

All the authentication related tasks are being handled by `\Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate` class. So, if you want to change the basic behavior of the auth middleware then you've to extend this class.

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate as BaseAuthenticator;

class Authenticate extends BaseAuthenticator
{
    protected function authenticate(array $guards)
    {
        // TO DO: do your desired change
    }
}
```

Comment: so where should I place the `Route [pages.notauth]` in `protected function authenticate(array $guards)` without using `php artisan:make auth`. so that if its not authenticated then it should go to my defined route of `pages.noauth`.

Comment: you can redirect to your desired url `return redirect('/register');` or you can raise an exception like so `throw new AuthenticationException('Unauthenticated.', $guards);`. It will depend on what you want to do.

Answer (score 1):

try to change this on app/Http/Middleware/Authenticate.php

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;
use Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate as Middleware;
class Authenticate extends Middleware{
    protected function redirectTo($request){
        if (! $request->expectsJson()) {
            return route('name your login route');
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try to add

```
Auth::routes();
```

in your  routes files to get rid of that error, `Auth::routes()` is just a helper class that helps you generate all the routes required for user authentication.

if you want to change the url add this instead and change it as you want :

```
// Authentication Routes...
$this->get('login', 'Auth\LoginController@showLoginForm')->name('login');
$this->post('login', 'Auth\LoginController@login');
$this->post('logout', 'Auth\LoginController@logout')->name('logout');

// Registration Routes...
$this->get('register', 'Auth\RegisterController@showRegistrationForm')->name('register');
$this->post('register', 'Auth\RegisterController@register');

// Password Reset Routes...
$this->get('password/reset', 'Auth\ForgotPasswordController@showLinkRequestForm');
$this->post('password/email', 'Auth\ForgotPasswordController@sendResetLinkEmail');
$this->get('password/reset/{token}', 'Auth\ResetPasswordController@showResetForm');
$this->post('password/reset', 'Auth\ResetPasswordController@reset');
```